# PostgreSQL CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION does not update function body

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, postgresql-14

[image]I have a function that exists in a PostgreSQL instance.  I can say that are several services running on an app server and pages served from a web server that both target the database.  Additionally, the DB is used to automate a plant and handles calls from a PLC (via a 3rd party card).  The function works well.  Normally, `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` updates the function body.  However now that we are testing in production, there are times when I need to update the body, I'll run `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`, and the function body does not update.  I have seen this behavior with several functions, for the first time a function that was called by both the app server and a PLC.  I thought if a thread was currently executing the function, maybe PostgreSQL indicates success on the DDL statement but does not actually update the function body.  Now, I'm seeing this behavior with a function that is only called by the PLC and I'm told no one at the plant is doing anything.  Why would `CREATE OR REPLACE [FUNCTION | PROCEDURE]` silently fail and not update the function/procedure body?  The first function was an actual function, the function that is only called by the PLC is actually a procedure but my understanding is that procedures are just functions that are invoked differently and don't return any values/tables.

Edit: I've added a screenshot after trying to update the function using DBeaver.  The left side is the generated DDL SQL from the function, the right side shows the changes (commenting out the `UPDATE` statement and uncommenting the `DELETE` statement).  The bottom right shows "success" of `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`.

Edit2: I guess I can chalk it up to DBeaver, even though I tried the same script (on hundreds of functions that work fine when I'm the only user logged in) on PG Admin as well.  What I was trying to do was execute the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` script in a script window in DBeaver.  Then, I would right click the "function" (found out PG Admin separates procedures from functions while DBeaver lists all under functions) in the object explorer in DBeaver, click Generate SQL, then click DDL to pop up the left window in the screen shot.  This was not actually saving the procedure change, though like I said, I've used the script window to create all of the functions/procedures and have updated them without issue before.  I got it to work by right clicking the function/procedure then clicking View Function, which allows editing of the source.  I made the desired change, right clicked the background, clicked Save, which popped up a dialog that had a Persist button on it.  I clicked Persist and then checked the definition.  This method finally persisted the change.  I can't explain it and I'll say again that I have modified numerous functions/procedures using `CREATE OR REPLACE [FUNCTION | PROCEDURE]` in script windows using both clients.

Comment: Your `CREATE OR REPLACE` probably resulted in an error (e.g. because the parameters or return type were changed), and therefor nothing was replaced. It will most certainly not "fail silently".

Comment: There were no changes in parameters or return type.  I'm well aware of PG's overloading and how you can't change types or names in the parameter/return list.  I've also tried updating the function using PG Admin and DBeaver.  Both have the same result.

Comment: Is it a procedure or is it a function? They are different objects since PostgreSQL 11+.

Comment: Let's consider the procedure.  This is PG 14 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would `CREATE OR REPLACE [FUNCTION | PROCEDURE]` silently fail and not update the function/procedure body?

**I wouldn't.** If the statement fails, an error message is issued. There must be some kind of misunderstanding, but we can't tell much from the rudimentary information in the question.

Comment: What can I add to provide more information?

Comment: @PhynyxRysyn Remove noise from your text blob, focus on relevant information, and format it. Show an actual (minimal!) `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` script. Provide formatted text, not images. Check the DB logs for any error message you may have missed. What's the output of `SHOW search_path;` in the same session? Are you connected to the right DB in the right DB cluster? Does it only happen with DBeaver, or can you reproduce the same with psql?

Comment: Thank you for describing what I can do to provide helpful info for people to answer.  I checked the logs and don't see my previous statements (`CREATE OR REPLACE`) in there, so I think it was a just a client issue.  I also didn't try psql and that's something I can try in the future.  Thanks again.